# C Compilation error when Python venv is being installed a module written in C

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, python-venv, pyenv-virtualenv

I am adding a new module to my Python “virtual environments”, [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html),(a module that converts .svg images to .png for documentation purposes)

When installing the venv I can see clearly a C compilation error.
After deleting my C compiler and installing another different C compiler the problem is solved - I assume Python uses the new C Compiler and hence now the compilation is working well, but I do need the other C Compiler as well.\n
After installing it again when installing venv I get the same C compilation error.

I am aware that some modules in Python are written in C for performance improvements, so I understand where the error is coming from.

My question is, How does Python choses which C compiler to use? can I force Python to use a certain C compiler?

Comment: Very likely, Python looks for `cc` in the path.  If it does not find that, then it may fall back to some other possibilities, such as `gcc`, `clang`, and `icc`.  You might be able to select a specific compiler by putting the full path to it in environment variable `CC` (note caps), and making sure that variable is marked for export.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.